# Steps feature in circular slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, circular-slider

I am using [Jquery Circular Slider](http://www.toolitup.com/circular-slider.html) and for the last few hours, I have been trying to add step feature in it. Like it should add step:20 in setting and then jump to plus or minus 20 from current location just like jquery UI slider.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin, which having all the similar options like the jQuery UI slider. And also you can easily customize the control and its [appearances](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#different-theming-and-appearances).

It supports default, min-range and range slider types. Not only the round slider it also supports various [circle shapes](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) such as quarter, half and pie circle shapes.

For more details check the [**demos**](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [**documentation**](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Please check the **demo** from [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/8/).